# get post by name of user or by id

Tags: django, django-models

i have this model

```
class Post(models.Model):   
    auth = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,default=1)    
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)    
    DESCSPECSOFT = (
    (u'Null','Null'),
    (u'Phone',u'Phone'),
    (u'Car',u'Car'),
    (u'Laptop',u'Laptop'),
    (u'jops',u'Jops'),
    (u'Electronic',u'Electronic'),
    (u'Clothes',u'Clothes'),
    (u'Makeup',u'Makeup'),
    (u'Furnishings',u'Furnishings'),
    (u'books',u'books'),
    (u'sports',u'sports'),
    (u'Property',u'Property'),
    (u'Other',u'Other'),
    )   
    City = (
    (u'Null','Null'),
    (u'Kosti',u'Kosti'),
    (u'Khartoum',u'Khartoum'),
    (u'Rabbik',u'Rabbik'),
    (u'Duwaim',u'Duwaim'),
    (u'Sinnar',u'Sinnar'),
    (u'Bahri',u'Bahri'),
    (u'Omdurman',u'Omdurman'),
    (u'Sawakin',u'Sawakin'),
    (u'Port Sudan',u'Port Sudan'),
    (u'Kasala',u'Kasala'),
    (u'Madani',u'Madani'),
    (u'Alabid',u'Alabid'),
    )  
    Case = (
    (u'Null','Null'),
    (u'New',u'New'),
    (u'Old',u'Old'),
    (u'Second Hand',u'Second Hand'),
    (u'Other',u'Other'),
    ) 

    Type = models.CharField(choices=DESCSPECSOFT, default='Null',blank = False,null = False,max_length=120)     
    company = models.CharField(max_length=120)  
    dis = models.TextField(default="in here you w,ll write all the discribtion about your product")     
    image = models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True,width_field="width_field", height_field="height_field")  
    width_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)    
    height_field = models.IntegerField(default=0)   
    case = models.CharField(choices=Case, default=99,blank = False,null = False,max_length=120)     
    price = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)   
    city = models.CharField(choices=City, default='Null',blank = False,null = False,max_length=120)     
    address = models.CharField(max_length=120)  
    draft = models.BooleanField(default=False)  
    #pup = models.DateField(auto_now=False,auto_now_add=False ,null=False)  
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True ,auto_now_add=False)  
    puplis = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False ,auto_now_add=True)

    objects = PostManager()

    def __str__(self):      
        return self.title

    def __unicode__(self):      
        return self.title
```

any user can add a post but i want the user name show in the data base means the user how add the post because every post show the admin name not the user how add the post can someone show me haw can i fix this ???
sorry my en is bad ...

Comment: Hi can you please rewrite your model details and tell me what you have to do.

Comment: i have field name auth up there its for user the default value for the field is 1 one means the admin i want thate value change with the user how log in and add a post

Comment: remove the default value from the field and add null=True,blank=True and when ever you save the data in to table add the user or select the user from` User` table.(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)

Comment: how? i can select the user?